# How to compare array 1[array of objects] with array 2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare with array 1 with array 2, array 1 has array of objects. whatever items available in array 2 those should be also available on array 1. If so, then, i have to push the item from array 2 to new array, then, i return newly created finalArray.
I did the code and it is working fine as i mentioned, But, this below code executes the 'for loop' many items that i don't want.

I wanted to avoid many loop execution.

```
var arr1 = [{"count":1,"name":"hitler"},{"count":1,"name":"cool"},{"count":1,"name":"cooola"},{"count":1,"name":"cute"},{"count":1,"name":"nyle"},{"count":1,"name":""},{"count":1,"name":"path"},{"count":1,"name":"root"},{"count":1,"name":"sssstag"},{"count":1,"name":"ssssu tag"},{"count":1,"name":"sutag"},{"count":1,"name":"tag2"},{"count":1,"name":"arrogant"},{"count":1,"name":"test01"},{"count":1,"name":"test10"},{"count":1,"name":"uber"},{"count":1,"name":"union"},{"count":1,"name":"assettag"},{"count":1,"name":"wire"}];

function intersect_arrays(a, b) {

    var matches = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
        for ( var e = 0; e < b.length; e++ ) {
            if ( a[i].name === b[e] ) matches.push( b[e] );
        }
    }
    return matches;
}


var arr2 = ["hilter","arrogant","cool","uber"];

var finalArray = intersect_arrays(arr1, arr2);
console.log(finalArray);
```

Anybody help me with better way to achieve the same?

Comment: You can optimise it by removing matched objects

Comment: you just want to match only base of the name property or the combination of some other property. In the example there are two property but you are matching with the name property

Comment: i just want to match with 'name' property

Comment: I don't think you can do better than nested for loops. For every element in `b`, you need to look at up to every element in `a`. Some of the answers you've received are more readable using higher order functions, but they're performing the same number of operations, I believe.

Comment: Also, why are you using "hitler" in your code? Odd choice. That name is associated with genocide for many people.

Comment: It is just a text, i just copied, am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace inner for-loops with

```
var matches = a.filter( function(item){ return b.indexOf( item.name ) > -1 } );
```

For example

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "count": 1,
  "name": "hitler"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "cool"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "cooola"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "cute"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "nyle"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": ""
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "path"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "root"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "sssstag"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "ssssu tag"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "sutag"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "tag2"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "arrogant"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "test01"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "test10"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "uber"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "union"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "assettag"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "wire"
}];

var arr2 = ["hilter", "arrogant", "cool", "uber"];

function intersect_arrays(a, b) {
  var matches = a.filter(function(item) {
    return b.indexOf(item.name) > -1
  });
  matches = matches.map( function(item){ return item.name } );
  return matches;
}

console.log(intersect_arrays(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to merge the arrays see Array.concat():
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

So your code would be this:
var mergedArray = arr1.concat(arr2);

This will just put them together. If you want to merge on conditions I think this isn't the best solution.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. Wrote this mobile, so no formatting is available. Will update.

Comment: You misunderstood. I dont want to merge, i want to check with array1, if it is available, then push to new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can Replace your two for loops with this

```
for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    if (b[e].indexOf(a[i].name) != -1) {
        matches.push( b[e] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more functional approach with `Array.reduce` and `Array.indexOf` to generate your result. This however is pretty much the same code that you have posted, but the ugly parts have been abstracted away.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {"count":1,"name":"hitler"},{"count":1,"name":"cool"}, 
  {"count":1,"name":"cooola"},{"count":1,"name":"cute"},
  {"count":1,"name":"nyle"},{"count":1,"name":""},
  {"count":1,"name":"path"},{"count":1,"name":"root"},
  {"count":1,"name":"sssstag"},{"count":1,"name":"ssssu tag"},
  {"count":1,"name":"sutag"},{"count":1,"name":"tag2"},
  {"count":1,"name":"arrogant"},{"count":1,"name":"test01"},
  {"count":1,"name":"test10"},{"count":1,"name":"uber"},
  {"count":1,"name":"union"},{"count":1,"name":"assettag"},
  {"count":1,"name":"wire"}
];

const arr2 = ["hilter","arrogant","cool","uber"];

const intersect_arrays = function(arr, keys) {
  // reduce the array of objects
  return arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
    // check if the name property is contained in the keys array
    if (~keys.indexOf(x.name)) {
      // add the name to the returned values
      return acc.concat(x.name)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])  
}  

console.log(intersect_arrays(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options:

**OPTION1**:

use **indexOf** to avoid the second loop.

```
var arr1 = [{"count":1,"name":"hitler"},{"count":1,"name":"cool"},{"count":1,"name":"cooola"},{"count":1,"name":"cute"},{"count":1,"name":"nyle"},{"count":1,"name":""},{"count":1,"name":"path"},{"count":1,"name":"root"},{"count":1,"name":"sssstag"},{"count":1,"name":"ssssu tag"},{"count":1,"name":"sutag"},{"count":1,"name":"tag2"},{"count":1,"name":"arrogant"},{"count":1,"name":"test01"},{"count":1,"name":"test10"},{"count":1,"name":"uber"},{"count":1,"name":"union"},{"count":1,"name":"assettag"},{"count":1,"name":"wire"}];

function intersect_arrays(a, b) {
var matches = [];        
a.forEach(function(item){
  if(b.indexOf(item.name) > -1) {
    matches.push(item.name);
  }
});
return matches;
}


var arr2 = ["hilter", "arrogant", "cool", "uber"];

var finalArray = intersect_arrays(arr1, arr2);

console.log(finalArray);
```

**OPTION 2:**

You could also use **filter** and **map** to do it in a more declarative way.

```
var arr1 = [{"count":1,"name":"hitler"},{"count":1,"name":"cool"},{"count":1,"name":"cooola"},{"count":1,"name":"cute"},{"count":1,"name":"nyle"},{"count":1,"name":""},{"count":1,"name":"path"},{"count":1,"name":"root"},{"count":1,"name":"sssstag"},{"count":1,"name":"ssssu tag"},{"count":1,"name":"sutag"},{"count":1,"name":"tag2"},{"count":1,"name":"arrogant"},{"count":1,"name":"test01"},{"count":1,"name":"test10"},{"count":1,"name":"uber"},{"count":1,"name":"union"},{"count":1,"name":"assettag"},{"count":1,"name":"wire"}];

function intersectArrays(a, b) {
return a.filter(function(item){
  return (b.indexOf(item.name) > -1)
});
}


var arr2 = ["hilter", "arrogant", "cool", "uber"];

var finalArray = intersectArrays(arr1, arr2).map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
});

console.log(finalArray);
```